# Creating macro to execute a single operation n times

Tags: c, macros

In my code I often have a for loop for doing a single operation n times. E.g:

```
// Wait for settle
    int delayLoop = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(delayLoop = 0; delayLoop < count; delayLoop++) {
    __NOP(); // operation to do
}
```

At first I wanted to make this as an function....but then I realized I do not know how to pass in the operations as a function argument.

In the above example the `__NOP()` is itself a macro that expands to:

```
__ASM volatile ("nop")
```

So how can I come up with a macro that I can call like this:

```
DO_LOOP(10, __NOP)
```

and what if I need to do more operations? e.g.

```
DO_LOOP(8, __NOP, myFunction(arg1))
```

that would expand to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
__NOP;
myFunction(arg1);
}
```

Comment: I would much rather prefer to see `delay_ms(5);` instead of `DO_LOOP(10, __NOP);`. Using macros can sometimes create hard-to-identify bugs, so I'd suggest staying away from such unneeded constructs. But, anyway, since `i` is a common identifier, you might get collisions if you use this inside a parent `for` loop (i.e. you would get a nested loop with the same identifier), so you might want to use a somewhat mangled loop variable (e.g. `i__` or something weird).

Comment: @Groo DO_LOOP is a good identifier for the loop counter.  I always derive my macro-local variables from the name of the macro (i.e., either use the name of the macro directly or something like THE_MACRO__var1, etc.). I think it's a bit more robust than names like i__, because if I'm already treating e.g., THE_MACRO as a macro, I'm extremely unlikely to make a variable named THE_MACRO much less also pass it to the THE_MACRO macro.

Comment: @Groo You are right but in my case I want to avoid a function call because of performance and I need exact cycle delays not a time based delay.

Comment: @DEKKER: time based or cycle based was just a suggestion to point out, obviously you can easily have `static inline void delay_cycles(int);` and it will be inlined and do what you're asking (unless you have a really old compiler). I just don't see much justification for introducing this macro, but that's just me - I feel the code would quickly become obfuscated if every developer on the team decided to introduce their own "smart macros" for these simple constructs.

Comment: Your original for loop is already the ideal way. The other macros are horrible obfuscation. Please don't invite your own secret macro languages. Other programmers know C. They don't know your secret macro language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define DO_LOOP(x, ...) for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) { __VA_ARGS__; } 

void f1() { printf("test\n"); }
void f2() { printf("a\n"); }   
int main()                     
{                              
  DO_LOOP(10, f1(), f2());     
  return 0;                    
}
```

`gcc -E test.c`:

```
void f1() { printf("test\n"); }
void f2() { printf("a\n"); }
int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { f1(), f2(); };
  return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work with inline assembly though. You can do something like:

```
#define DO2(x, a, b) for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) { a; b;}
```

and use:

```
DO2(10, __NOP(), f1());
```

Comment: Thanks. Why should it not work with inline assembly? any ideas?

Comment: The syntax mandates a semicolon after the inline assembly and here we have a comma. Updated.